# .htaccess - Set Document Root based on Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple static sites, everyone of them has the same domain pattern:

```
projectname.staging.example.com
```

Currently, I have to add a new ghost every time I'm adding a new staging environment.

Is it possible to set the document root in the `.htaccess` file based on the subdomain (eg. `projectname`)?

Answer (score 1):

No. The `.htaccess` is only evaluated after any URL mapping to work out what directory is to be used.

I would suggest you look at mass virtual hosting options in:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html